# archive build failed -> parse issue -> GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h -> module not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, apple-m1

I successed to run my flutter app on my macbook M1 and physical ios device. I can run `flutter build ios` with no error.

After I try to finish with archive on Xcode, I have build failed

```
Runner 
  -> Parse issue
    ->Module 'XXXX' not found
```

here is the pointer from GeneratedPluginRegistrant file

```
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#if __has_include(<app_review/AppReviewPlugin.h>)
#import <app_review/AppReviewPlugin.h>
#else
@import app_review;
#endif
```

Here is my PODFILE

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
...

...
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I have well set version deployment to 11 on xcode

```
I tried flutter clean
remove pods folder
pub get
pod install on ios folder
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`app_review`](https://pub.dev/packages/app_review) plugin only supports Android or iOS. It doesn't support macOS build. You can check the plugin supported platforms in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) right below the plugin title/version:

[image]

Comment: I don't want macos support just ios and android. All my plugins worked perfectly before apple force me to upgrade xcode, but due to small HD space, I change to a mac M1 with 1TO but now I can't archive without this error

Comment: Did you try already to uninstall `app_review` and reinstall it? `flutter pub remove app_review`

Comment: You can also try recreating the base files for the desired supported platforms with `flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,ios,android,web .`

Comment: remove app_review seems to unlock the archive loading. I wait to the finish. After I will try to resinstall to see... but I don't understand why now I can't use this plugin. I just upgrade Xcode

Comment: Archive successful finished, thank you ! Now I will try to understand. But I can already send upgrade to appstore (without rating, but not very important)

Comment: I reinstall app_review and archive works WTF xcode ...